# Ubuntu copying file problem (cannot stat file)

Tags: command-line, cp

I've faced a problem when copying a file with the commands,

```
cp ~/Downloads/sample.pdf ~/Desktop/
```

But the terminal gives me a message, `cp: cannot stat 'sample.pdf': No such file or directory`.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al` when you run it from ~/Downloads? You'll see the error you're seeing if there isn't a file of the **exact same name** present to be copied.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you verified that sample.pdf is the exact filename in the downloads folder?  It looks like the path is incorrect and that file doesn't actually exist there.  Try this...

`ll ~/Downloads`

See if `sample.pdf` shows up in the file list.

Comment: Actually I got a typo in the terminal, anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the file exists you have maybe not the correct permissions zu copy the file. Run in a terminal: `sudo chmod 775 /home/<user>/Downloads/sample.pdf` to grant yourself the permissions and  `sudo chown <your-user>:<your-user-group> /home/<user>/Downloads/sample.pdf` to own the file and try to copy it again. Your user-group shoul be the same value as your user.